# Blazor server: external login (facebook) assign policies

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-identity, blazor, blazor-server-side

I've created a new Blazor server-side application and added facebook external login.

I scaffolded the Identity Account/Register and in the PostAsync I can add users to a specific role etc...

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
      returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
      ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
        var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email };
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
          _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

          // Add all new users to the User role
          await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, CustomRoles.User);

          // check emails and assign them to specific roles
```

However when users register and login via facebook, this code is not triggered.

How can you add users who register and sign in via facebook external login to a specific role? 
Where in identity would this be done?